# Java - add webserver to application

Tags: java, webserver

I have java application running on VPS CentOS, but I would like to add simple webserver to this application, so I can load page and see actual status of running application (and maybe logs or restart some jobs), but I am not sure where to begin and what would be easiest and simplest way to add webserver into my application.

I have previously developed mvc web app in play-framework, but it would be overkill for such simple usage.

Comment: Stand up an com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer and handle the requests

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the usage of jetty (http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/).
Here is some code i wrote some time ago to help you get started:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOG.info("main");

        try {
            Server server = new Server(8080);
            HandlerList handlerList = new HandlerList();

            ResourceHandler resource_handler = new ResourceHandler();
            resource_handler.setDirectoriesListed(true);
//            resource_handler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{"index.html"});
            resource_handler.setResourceBase(".");

            LOG.info("setHandlers");
            handlerList.setHandlers(new Handler[]{
                resource_handler,
                new CncHandler(),
                new DefaultHandler()});
            server.setHandler(handlerList);

            LOG.info("start jetty");
            server.start();
            server.dumpStdErr();
            LOG.info("CncJetty started.");

            server.join(); //never returns
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JettyEmb.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

try with spring boot which can pack a embed jetty or tomcat server